# Execute public String

Tags: string, class, public

I have a public class EmailHelp.
In this class there is a public String called doIt.
How do i execute this public String DoIt from within let´s say a onClick event?

```
public class EmailHelp{
         -----
           public String DoIt {
              ------

public void crxExecute () {
          execute DoIt
            finish();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your development environment / language? Please add the relevant tags to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that "DoIt" is not a static method, you'd need to create an instance of the EmailHelp class, and call that method:

```
public void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var emailHelper = new EmailHelp();
    emailHelper.DoIt();
}
```

The fact that it's not obvious that you need to instantiate EmailHelper may indicate that the method should in fact be a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) one. If it were a static method, calling it would look like this:

```
public void Button_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailHelp.DoIt();
}
```